# Check box in a reactjs table

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement a reusable component for selecting the rows of a table using checkbox.I want a check box in header to select and deslect all the row too.I have to capture the values of selected row to fire some request from parent component.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain what you tried so far, what you couldn't achieve or understand, and how people could help you. Your question is too broad and does not show any personal effort to solve your problem.

There is a lot of libraries and/or design systems out there to implement tables with React, with a row selection feature :

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table
- https://material-ui.com/components/tables/
- https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-row-selection
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-row-select-table
- ...

You should try to find what's best for you among existing and well supported/tested solutions.

Comment: Hi Flo,thanks for reply.I tried with react-table.As given in example.I am not able to understand how to manage the state.As the component are uncontrolled.I just need a simple table with checkbox.I don't need pagination

Comment: OK, so trying this : https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/row-selection should be your best starting point (maybe that's what you already tried). The library holds the state (selected rows) for you, providing selectedRows and selectedRowId values through useTable hook.